Does any abbreviation especially used in writing?
One of printed English dictionaries says that abbreviation is a shorter form of a word or phrase, especially used in writing. Is the second part of sentence right for both America's and British English?

Yes, of course.

I would refine the definition: abbreviation is the shortening of the orthographic representation of a word or phrase, though sometimes the abbreviated form, if it can be pronounced, may be spoken.  A literate person does not say  "E-T-C" when they encounter the abbreviation "etc.", for example; they say "et cetera" but they might say "et al" when they encounter "et al.", not "et alia".

So-called "intelligent" speakers (like Google, Apple Siri, Amazon Alexa, GPS systems) will often say abbreviations incorrectly. When they encounter "N.W.", for example, they will say "N W" instead of "Northwest".

What is your reason for having a concern about "especially used in writing"?  Why do you doubt it to be correct in either American or in British English?

There's a modern trend to pronounce texting contractions as they could be sounded out, for example, lol pronounced 'loll' and lmao pronounced 'luh-mao', and I suspect that has not made it into many printed dictionaries (or perhaps they are in denial).

The question title is sufficiently ungrammatical that I can't tell what was intended.

There are plenty of very specific situations where abbreviations are exceptionally common. SMS, IRC, BBS, and Usenet are all famously known for use of abbreviations, as is in-game chat for most MMO, FPS, and MOBA games. And then there’s obviously cases like comments here on ELL.SE (or other stacks) where there’s a hard character limit, which actively encourages use of abbreviations. And that’s ignoring stuff like NASA, USA, laser, 3M, or amphetamine where an abbreviation is the ‘normal’ name for something used in everyday communications.

@TimR The opposite is sometimes true as well: I had a GPS navigation system once that, when it encountered a road named after the famous college football coach, said "Paul West Bryant Road" (the road was "Paul W Bryant Rd"; W was his middle initial).

@Hearth (and TimR) There's a village called Little Brickhill in the UK.  Signs often abbreviate it to Lt Brickhill. Google navigation reads that  as "Lieutenant Brickhill" (in the British pronunciation).  Reading NW as "N. W." instead of "Northwest" seems like the smaller error.

Google Maps in BrE voice routed me on the Millilitre King Parkway (Martin Luther King -> ML King -> Millilitre King)...

The question should read: Are abbreviations especially used in writing? OR Are only some abbreviations used in writing?

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany I think LOL as "loll" predates pronouncing LMAO as a word, at least here in the UK. RFOL as well, as in roflcopter from about 20 years ago. But TANSTAAFL has been pronounced as a word since Heinlein popularised it in the 60s.

@ChrisH I don't think I've run into TANSTAAFL. There are also a whole class of abbreviations that are usually considered too vulgar to read out in full, such as 'fubar' and 'milf'. And some that are easier to spell out than pronounce such as 'rtfm' and 'rch'.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany too vulgar and rather wordy.  RTFM could fit with FUBAR too, being NSFW (that's one that's normally read out in full) in many workplaces.

The question: Is it true that an abbreviation is a shorter form of a word or phrase, especially used in writing.
It's an interesting question. My immediate response was that the dictionary definition is definitely correct. But of course the word especially implies that this is a tendency, not an absolute rule. And given the vast range of abbreviations we should expect a range of patterns as between spoken and written English.
So as a personal thought exercise I looked up a random Wikipedia page and read it aloud to myself, looking at how I would say the various abbreviations in the written article. The page was for Ed Sheeran. Here's a sampler:

MBE (I would say this aloud letter by letter.)
four/15 (Those numbers were two of Sheeran's ages in the "early life section. Many larger numbers function as abbreviations in written form, but we say all these numbers in full.)
2010 (Similary, years are written as digits but spoken more fully: twenty ten or two thousand and ten.)
He played a session in St Pancras International (We would say St here as Saint.)
EP/DVD (These are standard musical abbreviations in both written and spoken contexts. We don't say that he released an Extended play record.)
The US/UK release of his next album (Here I can imagine variations. Both The US release and The United States release sound natural to me. Others may have different views.)
Number/No. 1 (This was sometimes abbreviated, but not always. But spoken English would always say the word Number in full.)

There were other examples, but the principle seems clear. Sometimes an abbreviation applied to both spoken and written settings. Sometimes the abbreviation applied in the written article, but not when spoken aloud. But I couldn't find an example the other way round, where an abbreviation was spoken but not written.

Many, if not most, Brits elide the word “saint” if it’s part of a name, (like snt) in St Pancras, St Werburghs (where I live), St Paul (in the Bible), etc. The given name St John is even pronounced Sinjun (see Norman St John-Stevas, the Tory politician).

Much depends on the specific word (and whether the context is formal or informal). Some words are more likely to be abbreviated in writing than speech, such as etc. (et cetera), St (Saint), e.g. (for example), vs (versus), Inc (Incorporated).
Other terms, such as info (information), stats (statistics), app (application), fridge (refrigerator), quote (quotation), isn't (is not), don't (do not) are more often written out in full, but abbreviated in speech.
I personally wouldn't like to say whether abbreviations overall are more common in one form than the other, but if the OP is citing an assertion from a published / printed dictionary, I wouldn't argue with that.
I don't for a moment suppose there's any significant difference between mainstream Englishes (British, American, Australian, Canadian, etc.)

+1 but note (@ЧёрныйМонах) that whether the words in the 2nd paragraph (words more often abbreviated in speech) are abbreviated in writing heavily depends on the writing style/medium; seeing the full form of any of those in an internal business email would be rare and mainly restricted to communications from upper management.  To my mind the first sentence of the answer applies more to this list than to the rets of the answer.

I think written communications channels such as SMS text messages and emails are a bit of a special case in this context. Increasingly slick predictive text and spelling autocorrection often actually make it easier to let the system write out words like information and application in full, even where you might not want to bother if you were using a pencil and paper.

SMS definitely; email covers such a range of registers and contexts it's harder to say

I'm not sure I would consider the words in the second paragraph to be abbreviations. They're just short words that happen to be derived from longer forms.

And "isn't" is a contraction, not an abbreviation.

Given the OP's level of English, I seriously doubt he's aware of any difference between an abbreviation and a contraction, let alone specifically interested in only being told about the former.
